# React page transitions using higher order components and framer motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, higher-order-functions, react-functional-component, framer-motion

I am trying to implement page transitions using framer motion in react JS. I have a layout file which basically contains the structure of my UI and I have wrapped my components in the AnimatePresence component given by framer motion for exit transition.

I also am making a HOC which will wrap my code inside a motion.div so that i wont have to copy paste the code for every page but rather can just wrap the export and the animation will be applied for the page. This is giving me an issue. If I import it consider named export it throws the error in the console -

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/HOC/PageTransitionWrapper.jsx?t=1684151786646' does not provide an export named 'PageWrapper' (at Home.jsx:19:9)

But if I import it as a default export it shows -

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:20439:25)
> at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:20460:23)
> at reconcileSingleElement (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:11801:31)
> at reconcileChildFibers2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:11838:43)
> at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:14292:37)
> at updateContextProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:15653:11)
> at beginWork (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:15943:22)
> at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:19749:22)
> at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:19194:20)
> at workLoopSync (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-INWTSBAG.js?v=d32c1a39:19133:13)

This is my RootLayout code:

```
  return (
    <Box>
      <Navbar />
      <AnimatePresence key={location.pathname}  initial={false}>
        <Outlet />
      </AnimatePresence>
    </Box>
  );
```

This is my HOC component:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const PageWrapper =(Page) =>{
  function HOC() {
    return (
      <motion.div
        initial={{ y: "100%" }}
        animate={{ y: "0%" }}
        transition={{ duration: 1, ease: "easeOut" }}
        exit={{ opacity: "1" }}
      >
        <Page />
      </motion.div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageWrapper;
```

And this is how I am using it in the home page

```
import PageWrapper from "../HOC/PageTransitionWrapper"

function Home() {
  return (
      <>MY CODE</>
  );
}

export default PageWrapper(Home)
```

I am trying to do something similar to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fYi8SGA20k&t=8393s) at 1:17:28 for the HOC and the framer motion concepts from [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4HYwsBRpRs).
Also if it matters I am using

> "framer-motion": "7.6.2"

and

> "react": "^18.2.0"